# change array value in specific index reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state like this

```js
const [tmp,setTmp] = useState(
    {status:false},
    {status:false},
    {status:false},
    {status:false}
)
```

how can I change status in tmp[2] ?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a completely new list of values with the help of the spread syntax to set the new value with a different reference.

```js
// Simply shallow copies the existing list. This is simply to make a new reference.
const newTmp = [...tmp]
// The object references inside aren't changed. But React will rerender children components anyway when the bit that uses `tmp` is rerendered.
newTmp[2].status = true
// You can also do this to get a new reference to the object
newTmp[2] = {status: true}
setTmp(newTmp)
```

The reason you want to provide a new value with a different reference is per React's requirement: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

If you simply do the following, it is not adequate since the reference to the array remains the same and React does not do deep equality check to find out if the new value is different.

```js
tmp[2].status = true
setTmp(tmp) // Does not adhere to React docs and will probably fail at rerendering
```

P.S. Among the JS data types, `Array`, `Function`, and `Object` are references. Do read up on checking equality with references if this isn't familiar to you.

Comment: Nice answer, the only thing I would point out it's Spread Syntax, not Destructuring Syntax..

Comment: @Keith Ah yes, thanks for catching that. I'll make a swift edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the array is a different reference to the existing, React will detect this as a change.   So you can clone the array, and then update the item at the index like shown by Daniel.

Or you can even use the normal JS array method slice to build a new array.

eg.

```
setTmp([...tmp.slice(0, 2), {status: true}, ...tmp.slice(3)]);
```

If you do this a lot, you could convert the above into a simple helper function.

```
function changeArrayItem(arr, ix, value) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, ix), value, ...arr.slice(ix +1)];
}

//use
setTemp(changeArrayItem(tmp, 2, {status:true});
```